# Share Clipboard with VNC Server on Ubuntu from Mac OS X Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, remote-desktop

I am unable to share clipboard from my Mac OS X 10.14.6 Mojave MBP to the remote Ubuntu 16.04 desktop running x11vnc or vino VNC server. I am able to copy/paste from remote Ubuntu to MBP. Cannot copy/paste the opposite way. I have already tried viewers from RealVNC, Tiger VNC and Chicken. Chicken works but it exits claiming the server is sending unknown tiles. It is unreliable.

I connect to remote using SSH tunnels. I have already set to True the following RealVNC properties: ClientCutText and ServerCutText.

Are there any reliable solutions?

Comment: I have posted one solution. Please feel free to post any other solutions, specially if they are free.

Answer (score 2):

The paid solution JollysFastVNC works. Instead of "Paste", I had to use "Paste as Keystrokes".